# How to check for undefined in javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to check for “undefined” in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/best-way-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript)

I want to make an if statement that if the value is not defined then let it go through.

I tried

```
if (something != "undefined")
```

and

```
if (something !== "undefined")
```

However it seems to go into the `if` statement no matter what. If it is undefined it goes through. If it is defined it goes through. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: A more complete answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/best-way-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript/3390426#3390426