# javascript: how to check a property is undefined

Tags: javascript

I have codes below.

```
elem.onkeypress=function(e){
 if( (e.which===undefined?e.keyCode:e.which)==13 ){
   //dosomething
  }
}
```

at IE8, it occus erros:  `'which' is null or not an object`

how to fix this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to check for "undefined" in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/best-way-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript) and others...

Comment: a little bit diffrence is this one is check wheather a property of a  Object is undefined, not a variable.

Comment: The problem's nothing to do with the `undefined` check of the `which` property. The problem is that `e` is undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `e` is undefined in IE because no event object is passed as a parameter to the event handler. You need the `window.event` property:

```
elem.onkeypress=function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
  if (charCode == 13) {
    //dosomething
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to go with `(e.hasOwnProperty('which') ? ...`

Answer (score 0):

use typeof:

`if (typeof e.which == 'undefined' ? e.keyCode : e.which) == 13)`