# Is variable set/defined issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forum, mybb

I'm using a forum software where you can pull up an avatar link using this: {$mybb->user['avatar']}

If no avatar is set then nothing is returned. I want to show an image if no avatar is set.

Currently the HTML is setup like this:

```
    <div id="avatar"><div style="background: url({$mybb->user['avatar']}) center center no-repeat;"></div></div>
```

The outer div is empty and in the background. This one is the one I'm adding a class too (.defaultavatar) so that a default avatar will display.

The inner div is the one with the avatar displaying. If no avatar is uploaded/selected then it will appear blank.

This is the javascript I'm using:

```
    var myavatar = {$mybb->user['avatar']};

    if(typeof(myavatar) = null){ 
        jQuery('#avatar').addClass('defaultavatar');
    }
```

If the avatar URL is empty I want the class defaultavatar to be added to the first div.

How can I do this (get it to work)?

Thanks very much,
Jack Clarke

Comment: to check typeof you should do `typeof(myavatar) === "undefined"`

Comment: You also might want to put quotes around '{$mybb->user['avatar']}', I assume the php variable is outputing a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two meanings for `undefined` in javascript. I'm not sure what their exact names are, for my example I will call them undefined and REALLY undefined.

The regular `undefined` is what you get when you try to get a value from something that has been declared but not initialized. In other words, the interpreter knows the thing you're talking about, but that thing has no value yet.

You can use a simple if statement to cast your variable to a boolean to check if it is this type of `undefined`. Be aware that this cast will also cast empty strings `''` and numeric `0` to `false` as well. If you need to consider empty strings and numeric `0` as well, use `myDeclaredVariable === undefined` for the condition instead.

```
if (myDeclaredVariable) {
    // myDeclaredVariable is initialized with a "truthy" value
} else {
    // myDeclaredVariable is either uninitialized or has a "falsey" value
}
```

The REALLY `undefined` is what you get when you try to access a random variable without ever even declaring it. The interpreter has no idea what you are talking about and it will throw a javascript exception if you try to do anything with it. To handle this situation, you need to use the [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

```
if (typeof myPossiblyDeclaredVariable !== 'undefined') {
    // myPossiblyDeclaredVariable has been declared
} else {
    // myPossiblyDeclaredVariable has not been declared yet
}
```

You can see a related StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/best-way-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript/3390426#3390426).

Answer (score 2):

in your `if` condition, the syntax has a problem. Single equal is assignment.

at least change this

```
if(typeof(myavatar) = null)
```

to

```
if (typeof myavatar == 'undefined')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 4 spaces indentation formats code with syntax highlighting. Or highlight and click the `{}` button in the toolbar

Comment: I changed it to what you said but it doesn't seem to be working. This is what the source shows:
    var myavatar = ;
    if(typeof(myavatar) == 'undefined'){ 
       jQuery('#avatar').addClass('defaultavatar');
    }

Comment: if('{$mybb->user['avatar']}' == ''){ 
 jQuery('#avatar').addClass('defaultavatar');
}

Comment: do you know which php template enginee the website app used? It's very similar with Smarty which the template enginee I use before, but it's definitely not Smarty syntax.

Comment: do you know which php template enginee the website app used? It's very similar with Smarty which the template enginee I use before, but it's definitely not Smarty syntax. you need to know the right template enginee to get right syntax. Alternatively,  you can try use alert() to check the value of myavatar. It should check whether the php syntax pass the right value to the javascript variable.  then you could know what kind of php 'null' value will be in this javascript

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what `{$mybb->user['avatar']` returns, it may be sufficient to do:

```
if (myavatar) {
  // do stuff
}
```