# difference between: if((typeof OA != 'undefined') && OA ) and if(OA)

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between: `if((typeof OA != 'undefined') && OA )` and `if(OA)`?

The former statement works; the latter quietly stops the execution of current function.

(maybe a rookie question)

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide some more context? Both statements are essentially  the same, but the second one will fail if `OA` was not even declared (i.e. `var OA;`). You should never be in the second situation, always declare variables (if they are not names of function parameters).

Comment: @FelixKling: I think that's the issue here.

Comment: @Rocket: Probably... it just seems odd... guess I haven't seen such code in a while ;) And using JSHint really helps too...

Comment: @FelixKling it is possible that OA is not existent.
One thing I don't understand is "fail": is it a bug, or code goes to else branch?

Answer (score 4):

`if(OA)` will fail if `OA` was never defined.  `typeof OA != 'undefined'` checks if `OA` is defined.

```
var OA;
if(OA){
}
```

This works.

```
if(OA){
}
```

This doesn't work: `OA is not defined`.

`typeof OA != 'undefined' && OA` checks if it's defined before trying to access the variable

Comment: +1, it's probably worth noting that `undefined` is false-y and your first example is not checking `null`, it's checking against `undefined`. People seem to get that confused. Not defined is not the same as the type `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

compiler wont try to evaluate OA incase of typeof  where as in it tries to evaluate in if(OA)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((typeof OA != 'undefined') && OA)
```

This will first check if the variable `OA` is defined. If it is, it will then be cast to a boolean and evaluated.

```
if(OA)
```

This assumes `OA` exists and immediately casts it to a boolean and evaluates it.

The second example will throw a javascript exception if the variable `OA` has never been declared - the first example avoids that.

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098816/is-variable-set-defined-issue/10099267#10099267) for more explanation on the multiple meanings of `undefined` in javascript.

Comment: Have double checked with try{}catch(){} to find out: ReferenceError: OA is not defined.
So, "not defined", which may cause run-time exception, is not "undefined", which is considered as falsy in boolean operations.  Clearly I am a rookie, but why is there the subtle difference?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098816/is-variable-set-defined-issue/10099267#10099267