# qUnit isn't running setup code like a browser would?

Tags: javascript, qunit, chutzpah

In stuff.js:

```
function init() {
    return "works";  // just here to ensure we can access this file from the test
}

window.MyNamespace = {};
```

In my test JS file:

```
/// <reference path="../../../project1/Shared/sub1/Javascript/stuff.js" />
test("foo test", function () {
    equal(init(), "works", "couldn't access source JS file");
    ok(window, "couldn't access source JS file");
    var ns = window.MyNamespace;
    ok(ns, "namespace is bad");
});
```

I get `namespace is bad` when running the above test using Chutzpah Test Adapter.  What am I doing wrong?  Shouldn't qUnit/Chutzpah have run the code in stuff.js before trying to run the test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed this the first time around.  Setting anything to the empty object works, but that reference still evaluates to false.  That is why the ok assertion fails.  I needed to do a more proper check for strictly undefined:

```
ok("ns" in window, "namespace is bad");
```

per the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript/13517037).