# "undefined" error when checking "undefined" in an if statement

Tags: javascript, object

I'm checking an `Object` (like an Associative Array) to see if a portion of data is available there or not, but I'm getting an `undefined` error exactly in the `if` statement where I'm checking if it is `undefined` or not!

I have an `Object` like this:

```
var data = {
    1: {
        2: {
            3: [
                ["a","b"],
                ["c","d"],
            ],
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried with `double-quotes` like: `var data = { "1": { "2": { ...`

These are the `if` statements which I've already tried. All of them failed, `Firebug` is generating `TypeError: data[1][2][3] is undefined` exactly in the `if` statement:

```
if (typeof data[1][2][3] == "undefined") {
if (data[1][2][3] === undefined) { 
// when I have double quotes
if (typeof data["1"]["2"]["3"] == "undefined") {
if (data["1"]["2"]["3"] === undefined) {
```

I checked that in jsfiddle.net and it works fine. I tried all the things I could imagine of, however I still don't have any idea why it fails in the `if` statement.

**Update**

look at this, oh god:

[image]

Comment: All is fine [here](http://jsbin.com/iyanic/1/)

Comment: You should check this using the in operator. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript

Comment: Can you try `alert(typeof data)` before the `if` condition

Comment: @Jack thanks, as I said it's my local machine issue I guess, I checked that in jsfiddle and it was fine ...

Comment: Well, your array constructs have trailing commas; that could be an issue.

Comment: @ArunPJohny it's `object`

Comment: @Jack firefox and chrome doesn't worry abt it, IE on the other hand will go crazy

Comment: @Jack remove them, nothing happened ... would it be a firefox|firebug issue?

Comment: wht abt `alert(data[1])`

Comment: Might as well tell us what `JSON.stringify(data)` gives you.

Comment: @ArunPJohny that works fine, if the item exists I can access it ...

Comment: can you create a small html file with case ans share it

Comment: @Jack that's also okay, everything same as I have in the object ...

Comment: @ArunPJohny first let me make an screenshot and update OP with it, then I will do that as well ...

Comment: @ArunPJohny I've updated with the screenshot ...

Comment: Your screenshot shows something different than what you said you where doing. You are trying to access `e.bubbles[2013][3][24]['layer_1']` – and the browser is complaining that `e.bubbles[2013][3][24]` does not exist, but you are trying to access a property of that anyway. So you failed to check for existence of `e.bubbles[2013][3][24]` before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some remarks, maybe the solution is in between:

Perhaps you want to use the negative version

```
if (typeof data[1][2][3] !== "undefined") {
```

since you seem to work on that data in the condition body, so you want to make sure it actually **is** defined inside your if condition? Atm, the code gets executed *if* the data is undefined.

Are you using exactly this object in your code or was this only for demonstration purposes? Because if you check `data[1][2][3]` and `data[1][2]` is already undefined, trying to access `data[1][2][3]` will throw an error because you are trying to access a property of a non existing object.

Sidenote: It might be more appropriate to use an array instead of a object if you have numeric indices?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm using objects because the data is quite nested. However I might switch to the `Array` if I couldn't solve it. Also I was using the negative check, it didn't work ...

Comment: @Mahdi Your console tells you exactly what i was stating with my second guess. You are trying to access `e.Bubbles[2013][3][4]["layer_1"]` but `e.Bubbles[2013][3][4]` does not exist, so it's property `["layer_1"]` of course does not exist too!

Answer (score 2):

If `variable[1][2][3]` is undefined, the script cannot check whether `variable[1][2][3][4]` is undefined or not. You should check for undefined for the entire depth of the tree

```
if(1 in variable)
{
  if(2 in variable[1])
  {
     if(3 in variable[1][2])
     {
       if(typeof variable[1][2][3][4] === 'undefined'){
          // Do something
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: The accepted answer is good enough (and more short-readable in the `try-catch` version) :) This just makes absolutely sure that the indexes exist, no matter what value they have, but in your case you shouldn't care about that

Comment: probably `if( variable || variable[1] || variable[1][2] /*||...*/ )` might be better suited (more compact and readable).

Answer (score 1):

Look at your output more closely:

```
if (typeof e.Bubbles["2013"]["3"]["24"]["layer_1"] === "undefined") {
> TypeError e.Bubbles[2013][3][24] is undefined
```

i.e., it's crapping out because your test is one level too deep.  The `["24"]` property doesn't exist so you can't possibly reach the `["layer_1"]` property.

Comment: Thanks! It works now! I really didn't know that, why it is so?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know beforehand whether you have all the hierarchy needed to get to the element you're checking (e.g., you're checking `e.Bubbles[2013][3][4]["layer_1"]`, but `e.Bubbles[2013]` doesn't exist, and you get `TypeError`), consider using error catching like this:

```
try {
    myData = e.Bubbles[2013][3][4]["layer_1"];
} catch (error) {
    myData = undefined;
    console.error("Couldn't get my data", error.name, error.message);
}

if (myData !== undefined) {
    // Do something with the data
}
```

At a cost of making code much less readable, you could also do something like this:

```
var _ref, _ref1, _ref2;
if ((_ref = e.Bubbles[2013]) != null ? (_ref1 = _ref[3]) != null ? (_ref2 = _ref1[4]) != null ? _ref2["layer_1"] : void 0 : void 0 : void 0) {
  // We know we have e.Bubbles[2013][3][4]["layer_1"] here
}
```

But I would recommend error catching.

Comment: yes, I was thinking about that as well, however in my mind `try-catch` is always expensive! I prefer light weight stuff ... but thanks for the suggestion again!

Comment: Well, if you really are dealing with tons of these comparisons on the client, then sure. =) But consider the overhead from multiple `if`s. In Python, for example, throwing an exception would probably be a preferred way to deal with such a problem.

Comment: Good point, I will make a simple benchmark to see which way is faster in javascript! :)

Comment: I'd added to my answer one way to do that using `if`s, but it's messy and inelegant. It's a JavaScript translation of neat CoffeeScript construction: `if e.Bubbles[2013]?[3]?[4]?["layer_1"]`. Note the question signs, they mean ‘don't go any deeper into the hierarchy if this key is undefined’.

Comment: That's interesting! Thanks, I guess I will go learn CoffeeScript soon! :D

Comment: Should point that `if(e.Bubbles[2013] != null)` will evaluate to true if the e.Bubbles[2013] is defined but has value of null. In many cases it should be enough, but it's best to know :)

Answer (score -1):

don't compare it with undefined...

if you want to check if its defined or not then just place it into the IF condition like...

```
var data = {
    1: {
        2: {
            3: [
                ["a","b"],
                ["c","d"],
            ],
        }
    }
}

if(data[1][2][3])
{
    alert("defined");
}
else
{
    alert("not defined");
}
```

Comment: falsy values? it will also trigger on `0`, `""`, `false` - it's always better to check for undefinedness!

Comment: `if(!variable)` will check for all the falsy values, not only for undefined. It is not good enough if you need to know if your var is defined or not

Comment: You might want to read http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/ or http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript for further information on that topic.