# How check object to undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have had object

```
dataSourceConfig.transport.read.url

remoteDataSourceConfig: { 
transport: {
        read: {
            url: null, 
        },
    },
},
```

How to check `dataSourceConfig.transport.read.url` for undefiend?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question crrectly, you have to check all the intermediary objects for existence:

```
if (dataSourceConfig &&
    dataSourceConfig.transport &&
    dataSourceConfig.transport.read &&
    dataSourceConfig.transport.read.url != null
) {
  // is not null or undefined
}
```

Otherwise you can do something like this:

```
function isKeySet(obj, key) {
  var keys = key.split('.');
  return keys.reduce(function(o,k){ return o[k]; }, obj) != null;
}

isKeySet(dataSourceConfig, 'transport.read.url'); // false
```

Comment: Are you know maybe there is function in javascript for this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no built-in function but `isKeySet` above should do.