# Check if values in array are defined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to populate an array with zeros and ones in such a way that if you arrange it into a 6 by 6 grid there will be randomly scattered ones directly adjacent to each other.

for example:
001101
111001
001011
001110
111000

In order to check whether or not there is a one next to a potential one I need to check 4 values of the array. This is where I'm having difficulty. I've tried implementing solutions from other questions on Stackoverflow, but I can't get it to work specifically with this if statement.

```
function initialize(){
    tile = new Array(6);
    first = true;
    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        tile[i] = new Array(6);
        for(j = 0; j < 6; j++){
            //This is where I'm having difficulty
            if(Math.random() < .75 && tile[i + 1][j + 1] != 'undefined' || tile[i - 1][j - 1] != 'undefined' || tile[i - 1][j + 1] != 'undefined' || tile[i + 1][j - 1] != 'undefined' || first){
                tile[i][j] = 1;
                first = false;
            }else{
                tile[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to add `typeof`

This is how you would normally check for undefined.

```
typeof tile[i - 1][j + 1] === 'undefined'
```

[More info on typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

---

Edit, per your comment, you're doing things like this

```
typeof tile[i - 1][j - 1] !== 'undefined'
```

and getting the error of

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined or Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '-1' of undefined.

Two things: that you're trying to access an index of -1 seems like it will always fail.  That said, even once you fix this off-by-one error, an expression like

```
tile[i - 1][j - 1]
```

will always error out if

```
tile[i - 1]
```

is itself undefined.  So you'd have to check it separately. Something like

```
(typeof tile[i - 1] === 'undefined' || typeof tile[i - 1][j + 1] === 'undefined')
```

This way if `tile[i - 1]` is undefined, the entire expression will "short circuit" before you get your error.

Comment: I've tried `if(Math.random() < .75 && typeof tile[i + 1][j + 1] !== 'undefined' || typeof tile[i - 1][j - 1]  !== 'undefined' || typeof tile[i - 1][j + 1]  !== 'undefined' || typeof tile[i + 1][j - 1]  !== 'undefined' || first)`, but I still get either _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined_ or _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '-1' of undefined_.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for equality with the string 'undefined' rather than with an undefined value. Try

```
tile[i + 1][j + 1] !== undefined
```

(no single quotes around undefined).

Discussion here: [How to check for "undefined" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript)

Comment: Or alternatively `typeof xyz !== 'undefined'` (`typeof` operator) to guard against old browsers that allow overwriting `undefined`. (edit: See Adam's post)

Comment: Last time I researched this, the approach of Adam Rackis was the best practice.