# Strange && operator behaviour in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

My node application just spat out this error, which I don't understand:

```
trendData && trendData.forEach(function(trendDataItem){
                       ^
TypeError: Object Error: HTTP Error undefined: undefined has no method 'forEach'
    at /home/myapp/node/dataSource/enabled/twitterTrending.js:9:36
```

The && operator should be preventing any `undefined` values of `trendData` reaching the second part of the expression, but it seems not to have worked. My understanding of node.js is that my code doesn't have to concern itself with multi-threading issues, so I assume there's no chance that the value of `trendData` changed between the evaluation of the first part of the expression and the second.

The `trendData` value is passed in from a callback made by a twitter library, source code [here](https://github.com/desmondmorris/node-twitter/blob/master/lib/twitter.js#L78), the line that is failing is inside the 'callback' function, from what I can see it should be the result of `JSON.parse` if everything worked, otherwise it will contain failure information.

Anybody have a clue what's going on?

Comment: What exactly is `trendData`? How is it defined? Any chance it was converted to string somehow?

Comment: Info about where trendData comes from added to question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript

Comment: It's not undefined, but an Error object with the name `HTTP Error undefined`

Comment: @Bergi - I think that's it, please turn your comment into an answer so I can lavish upvotes upon you

Comment: How exactly does that work? Is this in a condition, and if so, how exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, which means in this case `trendData` isn't `undefined` or some other falsy value, but instead is an object which doesn't have a `forEach` method.  Based on the limited snippet provided `trendData` is a string containing an error message rather than the array you are expecting.

Comment: That's what I would have assumed was happening, but the error message explicitly says that 'undefined has no method forEach'

Comment: @codebox: It says `HTTP Error undefined: undefined` has no method `forEach`. The stack trace format could be better.

Comment: Based on the twitter library that you're using the argument being passed to the callback is an error object, you can see the error construction on [line 97 of twitter.js](https://github.com/desmondmorris/node-twitter/blob/master/lib/twitter.js#L97).  It's not using the normal Node `callback(err, data)` convention, so you'll need to check for errors using `if (trendData instanceof Error) { ... }`.