# Javascript library to check string equality that is safe for undefined variables

Tags: javascript

Currently we have some code that is littered with statements like

```
if typeof myVar != 'undefined' && myVar === 'somevalue'
```

I'd like to consolidate that into a **single expression** that checks for a value in a way that is safe against undefined variables.  I realize I could write my own, but is it not part of any *commonly used* JS library?  It seems everyone else is satisfied with the code above, but I am not!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check for "undefined" in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript)

Comment: No. An in-place `typeof`-check is the only way to cope with undeclared (which seems to be what you meant by "undefined") variables. But you really really should have such anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all you need.

```
myVar === 'somevalue'
```

The `===` is strict for looking for a string.

```
var myVar = undefined; // or 27, null, false, 2.67, etc.
myVar === 'somevalue'; // evaluates to false
```

Comment: Does that protect against an `Uncaught reference` error, if `myVar` is undefined or null?

Comment: How to avoid "Uncaught ReferenceError: myVar is not defined"?

Comment: you should use `"use strict"` and always defining variables.

Comment: @KevinPauli: Define the variable. There hardly is a good reason not to do this. Otherwise, you just have to use `typeof`.

Comment: @Daniel This is still giving me the Uncaught ReferenceError http://jsfiddle.net/xqV2G/

Comment: @KevinPauli if you don't define the variable, it will potentially leak and lead to unintended consequences.

Comment: Okay, my example was oversimplified... in my case myVar is actually a function argument, so it is already defined.  I updated the fiddle to include that fact, and indeed the === comparison is all that is required: http://jsfiddle.net/xqV2G/2/ .  So I'm going to remove the superfluous checks for typeof 'undefined'.  Thanks!