# Case manipulating HTML5 data values in jQuery enumerable functions throwing an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The title looks a little confusing, so let me show an example:

Markup

```
<div id="MyDiv"></div>
<div id="SecondaryDiv"></div>
```

JS

```
// Set the HTML5 data key 'name' to value 'MyName'
$("#MyDiv").data("name", "MyName");

// Return all divs with the data key 'name' matching 'MyName'
//     This works without a hitch
$("div").filter(function () {
    return $(this).data("name") === "MyName";
});

// This breaks because I try to add '.toLowerCase()' to the end of the .data() function.
// The error returned is:
//     TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined
$("div").filter(function () {
    return $(this).data("name").toLowerCase() === "myname";
});
```

How can I ignore case when comparing `$(...).data(...)` values?

As a side note, even if I do this:

```
// This throw an error saying:
//     TypeError: val is undefined
var val = "";
$("div").filter(function() {
    val = $(this).data("name");
    return val.toLowerCase() === "myname";
});
```

Comment: try using "$("#MyDiv").data" instead of "$(this).data"

Comment: @MarvinSmit notice that it is in a `filter` function. I can't use `$("#MyDiv")` because I want to compare against every element in the initial selector. Not only against only `MyDiv`.

Comment: So are you setting the '.data' property of those div's anywhere? if not $(this).data("name") will return 'undefined'. on which you cannot call .toLowerCase().

Comment: @MarvinSmit As you see in the example I am setting it in the second line of the JS code.

Comment: That's only on the element with "MyDiv" as id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't run `.toLowerCase()` on `undefined`, so test if the return value for `.data('name')` is undefined first:

```
$("div").filter(function () {
    if ($(this).data("name")) {
        return $(this).data("name").toLowerCase() === "myname";
    } else {
        return false;
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/yX4X2/

or more succinctly:

```
$("div").filter(function () {
    return $(this).data("name") && ($(this).data("name").toLowerCase()==="myname");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/yX4X2/1/

---

(However, be aware that `$(this).data("name")` can potentially return "falsey" values like `false` or `0`, since `.data()` attempts to convert strings to their appropriate type. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript).)

Comment: Ooh that makes total sense! Thank you! As it's enumerating through each item, some will not have that data attribute, so calling a function on it will throw an error.

It's so obvious after it makes sense, lol.