# JavaScript - Best practice to check is function

Tags: javascript, callback

I saw many kinds of methods for checking callback function before calling.

1)

```
 function(callBack)    
      {    
           ...
           if(callBack != null)
              callBack();   
      }
```

2)

```
  function(callBack)    
          {    
               ...
               if(typeof callBack == 'function')
                  callBack();   
          }
```

3)

```
  function(callBack)    
          {    
               ...
               if(callBack !== null)
                  callBack();   
          }
```

4)

```
  function(callBack)    
          {    
               ...
               if(callBack != undefined)
                  callBack();   
          }
```

5)

```
   function(callBack)    
          {    
               ...
               try{    
                  callBack();  
                  } catch(err) {}

          }
```

6)

```
   function(callBack)    
          {    
               ...
                if (callBack && typeof(callBack) == "function")
                  callBack();   

          }
```

7)

```
    function(callBack)    
          {    
               ...
                if(callBack)
                  callBack();   

          }
```

8)

```
    function(callBack)    
              {    
                   ...
                    if(typeof window[callBack] === 'undefined')
                      callBack();   

              }
```

9)

```
  function(callBack)    
              {    
                   ...
                    if(callBack instanceof Function)
                      callBack();   

              }
```

I believe there is more...

What is the best way for checking if the given 'callBack' parameter is a function?

And why not to use the other examples.

Comment: I think `typeof(callback) === 'function'`.

Comment: Or simply do `callback = callback || noop` at the top of the function and execute the callback anywhere you want within the body.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> `if (callBack != null)`

Sure, why not. Notice there are still many non-function values that pass this.

> **`if (typeof callBack == 'function')`**

**That's exactly what you want.**

> `if (callBack !== null)`

No. Does not work when `callBack` is `undefined`.

> `if (callBack != undefined)`

Rather not. See [How to check for "undefined" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3390396/1048572) for why `null` is favoured (though equivalent).

> `try{ callBack(); } catch(err) {}`

Uh, possibly slower and swallowing any errors in the callback. If that is what you want, you should still combine it with one of the other tests.

> `if (callBack && typeof(callBack) == "function")`

Redundant, but possibly faster than a mere `typeof` test. You will want to test this if you care about performance, otherwise there's hardly a reason to be so verbose.

> `if (callBack)`

Sure, why not. Notice there are still many truthy non-function values that pass this.

> `if (typeof window[callBack] === 'undefined')`

No. This is absolutely doing a very different thing.

> `if (callBack instanceof Function)`

This should work for everything but some extreme edge cases, but using `typeof` is safer (and faster).

Answer (score 2):

I think strict check for`typeof` function

```
typeof(callback)==='function'.
```

Just wanted to point out these things also give type of `function`

```
typeof(Object)==='function' //returns true
typeof(Array)==='function' //returns true
typeof(String)==='function' //returns true
typeof(Date)==='function' //returns true
typeof(Object)==='function' //returns true
```

Comment: I don't see why you need to point that out; there is usually no real reason to pass a built-in constructor as a callback.

Answer (score 0):

Try with you Firefox or Chrome console

```
typeof someFunc === "function"
```

instanceof is slower

you can check performance here : [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/typeof-function-vs-instanceof-function/4)

Answer (score 0):

```
if($.isFunction(callback)) {
    callback();
}
```

Use $.isFunction(callback) to check callback is of function type or not.
this also checks for null/empty/undefined values.
if callback is of type function then returns true else false