# Checking boolean in default condition

Tags: javascript

Consider a variable `master` which can be `true` or `false`, never anything else.

Consider another variable `override` which can be `undefined`, `true` or `false`.

So how to determine which variable to use, if `override` is not `undefined` then use that otherwise use `master`.

Maybe we could do:

```
if ((master !== undefined && master) || override) then
   ...
```

But is this correct and also is there a better way?

Comment: possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that:

- `master` can only be `true` or `false`
- `override` can be `true`, `false` or `undefined`
- if `override` is not `undefined` then use it

So the correct code will be:

```
if (typeof override !== "undefined" ? override : master) {
    // use override
} else {
    // use master
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if( typeof override !== "undefined" ? override : master)
```

It's an unconventional use of the ternary operator, but it does exactly what you want:

If `override` is defined, use it. Otherwise, use `master`. If the chosen one is `true`, then...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you

```
if ((override === undefined && master) || (override !== undefined && override)) {
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Niet said, but I think it's clearer to store it in a variable.

```
var _set = ( typeof override !== 'undefined' ? override : master );

if ( _set ) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it in this way, which is more clear and easier to read.

```
var usethis;
if (typeof override != 'undefined') {
  usethis = override;
} else {
  usethis = master;
}

if (usethis) {
  // Enable feature X
}
```

You first check if the `override` variable is defined: if so we'll use that value, otherwise fall back to master. Then you actually use the value to enable a feature (I suppose that's your use case).

If you want, you can write that in this more compact way:

```
var usethis = typeof override != 'undefined' ? override : master;

if (usethis) {
  // Enable feature X
}
```

You *have* to use the `typeof` operator, otherwise type coercion will cast the `override` variable to boolean value, and you miss the `false` value.