# JavaScript - Common Function to check Undefiend and Null

Tags: javascript

I have a number of variables in my script, each of which could contain a value, undefined or null.

I've noticed alot of repetative code checking for undefined and nulls, can a common function be created?

I have created a common fucntion to check all variables are not undefined or null:

JS Original:

```
var testa;
var testb;
var testc;

if ((typeof testa == "undefined" || testa == null) && (typeof testa == "undefined" || testb == null) && (typeof testc == "undefined" || testc == null)) {
    //Do something ///////////
}
```

JS New:

```
var testa;
var testb;
var testc;

if (checkValues(testa) && checkValues(testb) && checkValues(testc)) {
    //Do something ///////////
}

function checkValues (v) {
    return (v == "undefined") || (v == null);
}
```

Which works. However what if testa contains a value, and testb and testc are null or undefiend? e.g:

```
if ((typeof testa == "undefined" || testa == null) && (typeof testa != "undefined" || testb != null) && (typeof testc != "undefined" || testc != null)) {
    //Do something ///////////
}
```

Comment: Then it will not enter in if block because you are using and condition.

Comment: There are a number of things that can go wrong with `checkValues`. Recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494 Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/

Comment: You can do something like `function isUndefOrNull(x) { return x === null || x === undefined; }`

Comment: Be aware of the difference between '==' and '===' when comparing nulls. Also have in count 'Nan' isnt undefined nor null, and you maybe want to check it too (check for 'Nan' is tricky, btw)

Comment: You forgot the `typeof` keyword in your `checkValues` function. It's looking for a string currently.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your use, according to your given condition "what if testa contains a value, and testb and testc are null or undefined" the as per your condition  it will return false.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a function to do that. `== null` will be true for both `undefined` and `null` values, so you need only this:

```
if (testa == null && testb == null && testc == null)
```

I assume you don't want to deal with *undeclared* variables, for which you *need* the `typeof … == "undefined"` test (and cannot use a helper function), see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3550319/1048572)