# Proper way to return value from recursion contained within for loop

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a function I'm using to recurse through a series of nested, tree node-like objects. Based on the console output, I can tell that all nodes are currently being visited. Here's the function:

```
function directoryRecurse(dir, searchedPath) {
    for (var ii = 0; ii < dir.children.length; ii++) {
        if (dir.children[ii].path && dir.children[ii].path === searchedPath) {
            return dir.children[ii];
        } else {
            directoryRecurse(dir.children[ii], searchedPath);
        }
    }
}
```

However, the return value is always `undefined`. I've tried modifying the function so that `directoryRecurse(dir.children[ii], searchedPath)` is replaced with `return directoryRecurse(dir.children[ii], searchedPath)`, but in this case the function terminates after the first leaf node is found. How do I ensure all nodes are visited and that the final return value is the node being searched for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `directoryRecurse` returns a dir if a match is found, and 'undefined' if no match is found... so you need to check which in your recursive call:

```
function directoryRecurse(dir, searchedPath) {
    for (var ii = 0; ii < dir.children.length; ii++) {
        if (dir.children[ii].path && dir.children[ii].path === searchedPath) {
            return dir.children[ii];
        } else {
            var result = directoryRecurse(dir.children[ii], searchedPath);
            if (typeof result != 'undefined') {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure of the Javascript syntax for `result !== undefined`, so anyone who knows feel free to correct.

Update: I think this answer ([How to check for "undefined" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript)) suggests typeof for this case of undefined, so updated accordingly.

Comment: This is perfect - thanks so much. Javascript is a little different than the rest of my experience in terms of returning from recursion.