# How to make this JS code executed only if statement is true? Set cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, setcookie, getvalue

Please help me to find a sutable solution for below in js:

1) I have a URL from referrer that contains two variables

- http://example.com/?**pdid**=**xxxx**&**puid**=**yyyy**

2) I have to catch **pdid** and **puid** variables form URL and set cookies with name POKUPON_DID and POKUPON_UID and their values

3) The main problem that cookies are set to **undefined** if URL does not contain this variables. I need your help with corect IF statement. The code should preform only once and if variables in URL are exist...

```js
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}

var $POKUPON_DID = getUrlVars()["pdid"];
var $POKUPON_UID = getUrlVars()["puid"];
 
if($POKUPON_DID != emty){
    
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;

}

setCookie("POKUPON_DID",$POKUPON_DID,30);
setCookie("POKUPON_UID",$POKUPON_UID,30);
}
```

Thank you a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be checking for undifiend read up on this: 
[How to check for "undefined" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript)

```
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;

}

var $POKUPON_DID = getUrlVars()["pdid"];
var $POKUPON_UID = getUrlVars()["puid"];
 console.log($POKUPON_DID);
 console.log($POKUPON_UID);

if(typeof $POKUPON_DID != 'undefined'){
setCookie("POKUPON_DID",$POKUPON_DID,30);
setCookie("POKUPON_UID",$POKUPON_UID,30);
}
```

Comment: I agree completly but as he asked: ". I need your help with corect IF statement. The code should preform only once and if variables in URL are exist..." and I've helped him with just that the if statement, God only knows why he's defining the function inside the if it's not like it creates scope anyway...

Comment: but by all means rewrite it for him :D

Comment: Thank you for reply, but every time I go to another page without variables in the URL  - cookies become UNDEFINED again :(

Comment: what if you console.log($POKUPON_UID); just below the definition?

Comment: And yes,  I am not a programmer so your help is valuable as never :)

Comment: what file do you have the javascript defined in?

Comment: the script is placed in  woorpa trigger

Comment: run script if url contains pdid an url contains puid

Comment: I mean this is an external script

Comment: christ what are you using there??

Comment: actually almost everything works. I can read variables from URL and set them too cookie but when I jump to another page - cookies values are undefined again(

Comment: check my updated snippet that seems to work for me here

Comment: Thank you for your patience..  I added a script in between <script> in <head> but it does not work properly. (please take a look at the page source zleep.com.ua). When I load a page WITH variables in url it really set them as cookies. But after exploring another pages on the site - cookies become UNDEFINED again... What's wrong?

Comment: you have something else removing the cookie..... if you run it in the console after the page load it sets it then the cookies are there when i navigate somewhere else...

Comment: how are you chking the cookies?

Comment: Do you have any ideas what it could be? main.html now is only one file where the code is placed...

Comment: it could be a thousand different things.. without seeing the source code it's realllly hard to tell

Comment: the code above does work though... if you could accept the answer that would be great :D