# How to check undefined in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

can we add check `undefined` value in `ng-init`.? if there is value in scope then print it else print `foobar`. Currently, it should print `foobar`
can we add a condition in `ng-init` ?

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/bFbAWXq6dKdkxWAxp7v8?p=preview

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="test|| 'foobar'">
    <p>Hello {{test}}!</p>
  </body>
```

Comment: use basic JavaScript Syntax - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

It's that simple:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="test = test|| 'aasasas'">
    <p>Hello {{test}}!</p>
</body>
```

You can write almost everything as you write in a Javascript expression/line.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/angular.js" data-semver="1.0.7"></script>
<div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="test = test|| 'aasasas'">
  <p>Hello {{test}}!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add conditions in `ng-init`

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="test = test ? test: 'aasasas'">
 <p>Hello {{test}}!</p>
</body>
```

the value of `test` will be `test` itself if its defined, otherwise 'aasasas'