# Javascript if undefined not working

Tags: javascript

I am using ternary expression to check if the variable exists to display value accordingly, but since, I need to check both if it exists and that is has some values in it, it fails on checking the condition when the variable is undefined. How can I fix that?

This is the code:

```
$('#select').selectize({
    items: typeof icoop != "undefined" && icoop != null ||  icoop.selectedUsers.length < 1 ? icoop.selectedUsers : []
});
```

I get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: icoop is not defined

Comment: icoop itself is undefined , you need to check first if icoop !== undefined.

Comment: First you need to have icoop object. Then tryto select it

Comment: For clarity, the reasoning behind the logic is correct but not the expression of that reasoning. What happens is that `typeof icoop != "undefined"` is **false**, which makes the entire AND condition also **false** but then you are left with, essentially, `false || ( icoop.selectedUsers.length < 1 ? icoop.selectedUsers : [] )` and because this is an OR, the evaluation will continue on the right, where the error occurs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`icoop` is `undefined`, so accessing any property or function will fail.

Check for `icoop` before checking for `icoop.selectedUsers`:

```
$('#select').selectize({
     items: (typeof icoop !== 'undefined' && icoop && icoop.selectedUsers && icoop.selectedUsers.length > 0) ? icoop.selectedUsers : []
});
```

You may also clean up the code a little bit:

```
// Check for icoop existence. Assign a default value if it is undefined or null.
var icoop = (typeof icoop !== 'undefined' && icoop) || {};

$('#select').selectize({
     items: (Array.isArray(icoop.selectedUsers) && icoop.selectedUsers) || []
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`items: icoop != undefined && typeof icoop.selectedUsers != "undefined" &&...`

also check out [How to check for "undefined" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript)

Comment: will still throw error when `icoop` is encountered if there is no such variable declared