# JavaScript - Can't check if variable is undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check if a variable is defined or not using the below:

```
if(variable.obj[0] === undefined){
 console.log("yes it's undefined !")
}
```

and also tried :

```
if ("undefined" === typeof variable.obj[0]) {
  console.log("variable is undefined");
}
```

However it throws on the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
at <anonymous>:1:16
```

Comment: It means that `variable.obj` is undefined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for "undefined" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript)

Comment: For my suggestion simple `if(var)` is enought to validate `null,undefined,empty,Nan` => `if(variable.obj[0])`

Comment: Hi @Folky.H! If one of the answers has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `obj` property is undefined. First, you need check `variable` and the `obj` property. After it you can access and check if `variable.obj[0]` is `undefined`.

Try:

```
if (variable && variable.obj && typeof variable.obj[0] === 'undefined'){
    console.log("yes it's undefined !")
}
```

Comment: This will say that the variable is defined even if `variable.obj` is not defined.

Comment: It will also get an error if `variable` is undefined.

Comment: @Emissary Sorry :) I changed `||` to `&&`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the containing objects first, before you can access a property or array index.

```
if (variable === undefined || variable.obj === undefined || variable.obj[0] == undefined) {
    console.log("yes it's undefined !")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

typeof does not check for existance of "parent" objects. You have to check all parts that might not exist.

Assuming variable.obj is an object you will need this code:

```
if (typeof variable === "object" && typeof variable.obj === "object" && variable.obj.hasOwnProperty("0"))
```

If it is an array then

```
if (typeof variable === "object" && typeof variable.obj === "object" && variable.obj.length > 0)
```