# Is there any benefit of checking typeof a === "undefined" instead of a === undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have been using `typeof` operator to check if a variable is not defined like this:

```
if( typeof numLines === "undefined" ){
  // do something
}
```

But the same can be achieved using:

```
if( numLines === undefined ){
  // do something
}
```

As far as I remember, I had read somewhere that the typeof approach is better but now I think why should I use a slightly longer statement if there is no benefit at all in that.  So my questions are:

1. Is there really any benefit in sticking to `typeof` approach for such checks?
2. Can you provide some examples where one approach is better than the other?

Thanks.

Comment: "undefined" is a string. whereas undefined is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript) `undefined` is not assured to be the thing you expect it to be:

```
var undefined = 'uh oh'

if (numLines === undefined) {
  // Seems safe but isn't
}
else if (typeof(numlines) == 'undefined') {
  // Actually gets it.
}
```

It's very odd that `undefined` is not nailed down in JavaScript, but that's how it is with the ECMA standard.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I'm not sure that's a fix. That seems like clarification.

Comment: It's now only possibly with variable shadowing, as of ES5.1: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.1.3 (the global undefined is immutable)

Comment: Hopefully someone, somewhere, will petition for a `defined()` function in JavaScript. Until then there's a reason to use things like Underscore.

Comment: Meh, the function name could just be shadowed. Then the same shadowing issue applies.

Comment: Having a dependable default would be a nice touch, but that's not how modern JavaScript seems to roll.

Comment: Thanks @tadman But if we assume that `undefined` was tempered with, same argument could go with `typeof` function itself that it might be redefined somewhere. Is it a possibility?

Comment: There's some things you can't monkey with in JavaScript, they're defined as [reserved keywords](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Reserved_keywords_as_of_ECMAScript_2015), and `typeof` is one of them. For reasons nobody has ever reasonably explained, `undefined` did not make this list.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot @tadman