# Not condition in javascript for number

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I came across a condition which made me strange. I am working on React in that I have given a condition on a render method like this:

```
 if (!this.props.allYearData || !this.props.Growth)
      return <Loading />;
```

However, my page always shows the loading symbol. I console data what I have given in if condition and both data was in define state, but my Growth was showing 0 value., so I commented out `this.props.Growth` and my page loaded. So I am just wondering why JavasSript didn't consider 0 as a defined value? I always has impression that `!` means `undefined`. Can someone explain this?

Comment: couple of good reads. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3390426/2315280 https://stackoverflow.com/a/19839953/2315280

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your impression of the ! operator is fairly off in JS (and most other languages). It doesn't mean undefined, it generally always means "not", so:

```
if (!condition)
```

means "if condition is not true"

false, undefined, null, 0 and an empty string like '' will all return "falsey" in javascript if used in a conditional operator like if, while everything else will return "truthy". This is a fairly standard practice in most loosely typed languages, you find similar behavior in python, though one important difference is that in JS, an empty array is NOT falsey, whereas in python it is.

If you ONLY want to know if the value is not undefined, it's simple:

```
 if (this.props.allYearData !== undefined || this.props.Growth !== undefined)
```

Answer (score 3):

`0` is falsy. `!` is a negation operator. Thus `!0` is going to be "not falsy" or truthy. Truthy values in an `if` statement condition result in the `if` block will be evaluated.

---

### Details

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) for more information on Truthy/Falsy.

Here are a few examples:

```
true     // truthy
false    // falsy
!true    // falsy (negation operator, it says "opposite of")
!false   // truthy
0        // falsy (this is because booleans are represented as 0 and 1 in binary,
         //        0 being false)
!0       // truthy
undefined // falsy
!undefined // truthy
```

Comment: can you please bit elaborate it?

Comment: Putting `!` in front of something "negates" it, i.e. makes it "the opposite". If you have something that is `true`, putting an `!` in front of it will make it ?false`: `!true === false`, for instance. `0` is considered `false`, so if you put `!` in front of something false, it becomes `true`.

Comment: JavaScript will evaluate a number of things to false - The number 0, an empty string, `NaN`, and `undefined` will all evaluate to false.  negating a falsey value results in true.  It's best to be careful about how you evaluate values because these so called "falsey" values (values that are not "false" but evaluate to false) can cause unexpected results.  A more specific test will often prevent this.