# How to check if object value exists using 'in' operator/callback

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
arrFrom = [{a: 1, b: 1}, {a: 1, b: undefined}]
arrTo = []
```

And I try to create new arrTo from arrFrom:

```
for (let value of arrFrom){
arrTo.push({x: value.a, y: value.b })
}
```

I need to catch undefined value. 
I know, I can use function or operators like:

```
arrTo.push({x: value.a, y: value.b || 0 })
arrTo.push({x: value.a, y: value.b ? value.b: 0 })
```

Can I use 'in' operator/callback/other style?

EDIT:
Thanks for comments, 
I meant if could use syntax like this(this doesn't work):

```
arrTo.push({x: value.a, y: ('undefined' in value.b) ? true: 0 })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for "undefined" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript)

Comment: Your dot notation is backwards. It should be `value.a` and `value.b`.

Comment: What's wrong with the solutions you've already proposed? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arrTo.push({x: a.value, y: b.value || 0 })
```

I think this is non a OP, 0 will never be applied because always false.
Then you can use :

```
arrTo.push({x: a.value, y: ('value' in b) ? b.value: 0 })
```

checking undefined is a long story but I always used :

```
typeof value != 'undefined' && value !== null
```

Comment: `a` and `b` aren't defined variables, `value` is, and `a` and `b` are the fields of `value`.

Comment: Thanks for idea, unfortunately this doesn't work
`arrTo.push({x: a.value, y: ('undefined' in b) ? true: 0 })`

Comment: obj = {a:1 , b:undefined}
copy = {};
if( 'b' in obj)   copy.b = obj.b;
You need to read some Javascript book first...

Answer (score 0):

You meant to do like this:

```
arrFrom = [{a: 1, b: 1}, {a: 1, b: undefined}];
arrTo = [];
for (var value of arrFrom){
arrTo.push({x: value.a, y: value.b || 0 })
}
console.log(arrTo); // [ { "x": 1, "y": 1 }, { "x": 1, "y": 0 } ]
```