# Javascript, how to check if object exists

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making a script in Javascript script that gets a SQL response, then processes it. Basically, I want to check if the username value exists in `result[1]`. When it checks, it errors out and says that it does not exist. If it does not exist, I want it to return false, not stop the program.

Here is the code:

```
if (result[1].username != undefined) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

I have tried using `typeof(result1) == undefined`, but it gives me the same error.

Comment: You need to use strict comparison `!==` instead of weak comparison `!=`. For `typeof()` check you need to compare with string `'undefined'` instead of `undefined` instead as `typeof()` returns string. Also you have `result1` instead of `result[1]`, maybe it is a reason.

Comment: it is dependent of you sql api. basically you could check if the element of th array exists, if the property exits and/or if the vlaue is truthy or not empty string.

Comment: Can you specify what error you are getting

Comment: This can't be answered without guessing until the error message being received is given. At this point for all we know `result[1]` might not even exist. Once we have more info this can be dupe closed.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-a-key-exists-in-a-javascript-object | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to make sure the result exists, otherwise you'd be indexing into `undefined` which would crash your application.

Second, you can make that check less verbose with:

```
return (result[1] && result[1].username)
```

which will return a falsey value if it doesn't exist, and whatever the username is, if it does.

In case you need an explicit `true` to be what the function returns, you can coerce it:

```
return (result[1] && (result[1].username && true))
```

I would make sure to refactor for readability, but that's the gist.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in). For example:

```js
let trueObj = { username: 'Foo' };
let falseObj = { };

if ('username' in trueObj) {
  console.log('username found in trueObj');
} else {
  console.log('username not found in trueObj')
}

if ('username' in falseObj) {
  console.log('username found in falseObj');
} else {
  console.log('username not found in falseObj')
}
```

Answer (score -2):

First of all please check whether the result itself exists or not and make the corresponding **&** operator and i think this will definitely help

```
if (result && result[1] && result[1].username) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

But if you don't want to make your code complex then you can try lodash library.
https://lodash.com/