# Why is if (undefined) evaluating to true?

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm new to JavaScript and have hit what seems to be an obvious issue.

```
const item = sessionStorage.getItem('item'); // undefined
if (item) {
    return item;
}
```

In the Chrome debugger I can see that item is coming back as **undefined**. I would expect the conditional to fail. To my surprise it's evaluating to true.

I thought I'd already tested this out. Why would it be coming back as true in the conditional?

I've come across other checks such as those recommended by [How to check for "undefined" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript). But... why do I have to do anything even remotely 'complex' for a simple check like this? The above approach seems so simple and elegant I'm reluctant to lose it.

I'm also seeing this approach in an example on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're not getting the value `undefined` from sessionStorage, but the string `"undefined"`, which is truthy just like any other non-empty string.

I know you're not getting the value `undefined` because that is impossible. `sessionStorage.getItem` can only return a string or `null`. Also note that `setItem` will coerce its argument to a string, so `sessionStorage.setItem('item', undefined)` sets item to the string `"undefined"`.

If you want to remove an item you should use `sessionStorage.removeItem('item');` instead of setting it to `undefined`.

Comment: And you're 100% right. Found that the value was set to the string "undefined" in sessionStorage. Thank you.