# Proper use of undefined

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have someArray that at runtime will have either 0 or 1 elements.

Would this be a valid use of undefined?

```
var validItem = someArray[0];
if (validItem !== undefined) {
    validItem.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: I mean, it works... did you test it? What do you consider "valid use"? This question is a bit vague.

Comment: Why do you test something that you say will always be true?

Comment: better use `(!! validItem)` for truthy/falsy

Comment: You will get loads of answer for the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript)

Comment: Your check will fail if you have this `someArray = [undefined, 1];` which is a perfectly valid Javascript array.

Comment: @AntihypeBird What if `validItem` is an empty string? Or the number `0`? Or the bool `false`? Catching specifically `undefined` vs catching *any falsy value* are very, very different.

Comment: I mean, it works, but am I using "undefined" behavior of JavaScript that will vary across implementations? It saves me a length check, but would it be comprehensible to another developer? Is it bad practice?

Comment: @TylerRoper What if `someArray = new Array(1);`? This will result in an array with length 1 and look like this: `[ undefined ]`;

Comment: Not really. You're checking that the **first** key of validItem is not undefined. If you try and access the **second** you'd be SOL. Checking the _length_ of the array would be better in almost all cases.

Comment: @connexo Fair enough. I suppose we could really go back and forth coming up with outliers for each and every solution. Without knowing the actual context around the question I don't think we'll be able to say "What is valid" to any certainty.

Comment: Why not just use `.length`?

Comment: Let me change the scenario to make things a bit clearer...

Comment: @Pointy See my previous comment on Tyler Roper's comments.

Comment: @connexo ooooh, that's nifty :D

Comment: Given the feedback, should I just delete this and re-ask the question with some of these details already filled in?

Comment: And perhaps I could include a minimal runnable example?

Comment: I'd say it could be marginally useful as it was before your edit.

Comment: If you're really looking through an array of *objects* and using `.find()`, then I'd just use `if (validItem)`.  It'll either be an object reference, and thus truthy, or it'll be nothing and thus falsy.

Comment: @Pointy To keep this from getting messier than it already is, I reverted my edits so the question matches the answers. With what I've learned, I will ask a more precise question that includes ".find()"

Answer (score 1):

this will throw you an exception if elements has no elements and you reference someArray[0];
it will throw you an error
you should check like this

```
    if(someArray.length){
  someArray[0].doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to make sure you don't try to call a function on `undefined`, this is what I would do:

```
var validItem = someArray[0];
if ('doSomething' in validItem && typeof validItem.doSomething === 'function') {
    validItem.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: My intention is to avoid hitting someArray more than once - for the sake of argument, suppose someArray can change at any time. So if I do a "someArray.length > 0" test and then try to use an element "someArray[0].doSomething()", there are no guaruntees that it hasn't become empty since I checked. So instead, I was hoping to just "get" the first item in the list and then make the decision of whether it exists or not by checking against undefined before using it.