# How to skip undefined value in loop?

Tags: javascript

This is the log:

```
0: 89392
1: 4454
2: 196406
3: undefined
4: 181473
5: 35547
6: 26040
7: 102495
8: 96180
9: 20733
10: 33113
11: 86545
12: 25397
13: 4718
14: 40053
15: 51517
16: 9026
17: 26811
18: 63626
19: 18050
```

Tried:

```
var casiTestati = filtererdData.map(vd => {
    var testatiValid = vd.data.casi_testati;
    if(testatiValid != "") {
        if(firstRunMap) {
            return vd.data[vd.data.length - 1].casi_testati;
        }
        return vd.data[vd.data.length - 1].casi_testati - vd.data[0].casi_testati;
    }
});
```

Also tried testing with:

`if(!testatiValid)` and `if(testatiValid = undefined)` and `if(typeof testatiValid !== 'undefined') {`

But I still get `undefined` value

Actually doing:

`if(typeof testatiValid !== 'undefined') {`

Gives me all values as undefined

Comment: use filter function instead of map

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check for "undefined" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript)

Comment: @afghanimah I tried if (typeof myVar !== 'undefined') as the question says but no

Comment: @Colin why would that resolve the issue? Mind an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array#map` will always return an array of the same length as the input one - you can't skip any values. There are two easy approaches to this problem.

1.
Use an `Array#filter` after the `map` to filter out undefined values (may be slow on large data sets as it requires two loops)

```
var casiTestati = filtererdData.map(vd => {
    var testatiValid = vd.data.casi_testati;
    if(testatiValid != "") {
        if(firstRunMap) {
            return vd.data[vd.data.length - 1].casi_testati;
        }
        return vd.data[vd.data.length - 1].casi_testati - vd.data[0].casi_testati;
    }
}).filter(vd => vd !== undefined); //<-- filter out undefined values
```

2.
Use a normal loop or reduce instead of a map and add values to the result array manually

```
var casiTestati = filtererdData.reduce((ct,vd) => {
    var testatiValid = vd.data.casi_testati;
    if(testatiValid != "") {
        if(firstRunMap) {
            ct.push(vd.data[vd.data.length - 1].casi_testati);
        }
        ct.push(vd.data[vd.data.length - 1].casi_testati - vd.data[0].casi_testati);
    }
}, []);
```

---

**Explanation:**

From your comments on the other answers, it seems like some of your data has an undefined `casi_testati` property. You would have to manually check the first and last `data[...].casi_testati` and simply not push the value in the 2nd case. But in the first case you allow some invalid data and just filter it out afterwards. Both approaches are perfectly OK.

Comment: tried to use the second one and I got (http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code(40) [89392, 89392, 4454, 4454, 196406, 196406, undefined, NaN, 181473, 181473, 35547, 35547, 26040, 26040, 102495, 102495, 96180, 96180, 20733, 20733, 33113, 33113, 86545, 86545, 25397, 25397, 4718, 4718, 40053, 40053, 51517, 51517, 9026, 9026, 26811, 26811, 63626, 63626, 18050, 18050](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code

Comment: @rob.m It looks like your `casi_testati` property is sometimes undefined. You should check for this and not push values if it is invalid. Or you can use the first approach and just filter out all bad values afterwards.

Comment: ok your first piece works! Damn I want to understand why now, because it doesn't make sense to me

Comment: @rob.m I attempted to explain more in the edit, please give it a look and see if it helps.

Comment: this will be a nightmare, now we have another case where we need to use it, but we get NaN                         `var totCasiTestati = regionData.data[regionData.data.length - 1].casi_testati - regionData.data[0].casi_testati;`

Comment: that is within this `filtererdData.forEach((regionData) => {`

Comment: @rob.m You're doing a subtraction between `vd.data[vd.data.length-1].casi_testati` and `vd.data[0].casi_testati`. If either of those are undefined, the result of subtraction is NaN. You can either filter out NaN values too with method #1 or perform a check first and don't push any value if it will be NaN in method #2.

Comment: Given how browsers do optimize js, having first a filter then a map might actually be a lot faster on big data. Even though it'll loop two times, the branching you create will force the code to be deoptimized.

Answer (score 0):

You should filter your results first to get rid of undefined value first:
`filtererdData.filter(x => x !== undefined).map(x => {...})`.

Comment: this still gives me one undefined                         `var casiTestati = filtererdData.filter(vd => vd !== undefined).map(vd => {
                            if(firstRunMap) {
                                return vd.data[vd.data.length - 1].casi_testati;
                            }
                            return vd.data[vd.data.length - 1].casi_testati - vd.data[0].casi_testati;
                        });
                    }
                    
                    console.log(casiTestati);`

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.map` never removes any values.

You can run `Array.prototype.filter` first:

```js
var casiTestati = filtererdData.filter(vd => vd !== undefined).map(vd => {
    // your code
});
```

If you want to do both at the same time, there's also `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```js
var casiTestati = filtererdData.reduce((carry, item) => {
    if (item === undefined) return carry;

    const newItem = /* your code */;

    carry.push(newItem);
}, []);
```

Comment: this still gives me one undefined                         `var casiTestati = filtererdData.filter(vd => vd !== undefined).map(vd => {
                            if(firstRunMap) {
                                return vd.data[vd.data.length - 1].casi_testati;
                            }
                            return vd.data[vd.data.length - 1].casi_testati - vd.data[0].casi_testati;
                        });
                    }
                    
                    console.log(casiTestati);`

Comment: Probably your `.map()` returns `undefined` for some items.

Comment: it is indeed, check the comment I made for Klaycon, tried his second piece with a normal loop but still

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in this line:

```
var testatiValid = vd.data.casi_testati;
```

Elsewhere you are treating `vd.data` as an array. `vd.data.casi_testati` will always be `undefined`.

You'll want to move your falsey check to `if(vd.data[vd.data.length - 1].casi_testati)` or `if (vd.data[0].casi_testati)`. Look at the return values.