# I encountered an if statement problem in Vuetify method

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework, vuex, vuetify.js

I have been following a Django REST + vue.js tutorial and have encountered a problem in the end.

The task is to POST a new query if the id does not exist, edit otherwise.

The tutorial provides the following code for the purpose:

```
submitForm(){
  if (this.movie.id === undefined) {
    this.createMovie();
  }
  else {
    this.editMovie();
  }
```

I have confirmed that both `createMovie` and `editMovie` functions work properly, but the query does not enter the `createMovie` section despite having no data that matches the provided id.

My solution was to introduce a new Boolean variable `is_edit`, which would turn `True` after clicking on the edit button, but the solution rendered the problem much more complex and I have no idea to proceed.

That said, is there any solution similar to the one that the tutorial provides?

Just in case, the link to the tutorial is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7GWKv03Osek
and for the entire project, https://github.com/Treeboy2762/app

Huge gratitude in advance!

Comment: Try out `this.movie.id?this.editMovie():this.createMovie()`

Comment: on first u can use condition without "=" like
```
if (this.movie.id) {
    this.createMovie();
  }
  else {
    this.editMovie();
  }
```

Comment: Huge thanks! the problem is solved surprisingly with Mykyta's suggestion.

Comment: I think you'll find this discussion quite interesting too (be sure to read both the first and second answers): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-can-i-check-for-undefined-in-javascript