# How to check if an input is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

So i have a function, lets say:

```js
function a(string).....
```

and i want to check if the string is undefind. if it is do something
The code would look something like this:

```
function a(string){
 if(string == null){
 //do something
 }
 else{
 //do another thing
 }
```

The problem is it doesn't seem to work, even if the string isn't declared its still going to call the else. Maybe we could try doing

```js
 if(string == "undefind"){
 //do something
 }
 else{
 //do something else
 }
```

but yet it doesn't seem to change anything. null and undefind seem to work in the same way. Is there a specific function from a library that allows the checking if an input is declared? is there a way you could check it directly from the input with something like

```js
if(string.isDeclared()==true){
//do something
}
else{
//do something else
}
```

Comment: typeof myVar === 'undefined'

Comment: Check on strict equality of `undefined`

Comment: *"The problem is it doesn't seem to work, even if the string isn't declared its still going to call the else."* Yes, [that works](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/58zakdmb/). It will branch into the `if` branch if `string` is either `null` or `undefined`. `string == "undefined"` will only check if it's the **string** value `"undefined"`.

Comment: Yes agree with @T.J.Crowder, the equality check must be on `undefined` outside of a string enclosure. Spelling mistakes with "undefind" not relevant when enclosed in quotes.

Comment: This topic is **very** well-covered by previous questions and answers, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-can-i-check-for-undefined-in-javascript) which is a duplicate of several others.

Comment: ty i fixed it and now all works well :D

Comment: and the suggestion to go bring undefined outside quotes it's not correct. You can check yourself on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined where it says it can be done also quoting undefined.

Comment: @DiegoDeVita just followed your link. No where in it is `undefined` in quotes. There is mention of `type of` where quotes are allowed however.

Comment: @mardubbles check better: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined#typeof_operator_and_undefined

Comment: OP doesn't use `type of` @DiegoDeVita