# how to check for an attribute that can be undefined or have a value in Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check for an attribute inside the Jquery Mobile transition data object. The attribute can either be *undefined* or has a value of *dialog* or some other value.

Originally I only checked like this:

```
$(document).on( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {
    if(  A && B && data.options.role != "dialog" ){
        // do something
        }
     });
```

However, this way I never enter the if-clause when *data.options.role* is undefined. I'm currently trying like this but am not really getting anywhere:

```
$(document).on( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {
    if(  A && B && data.options.role != "undefined" && data.options.role != "dialog" ){
        // do something
        }
     });
```

**Question**
How can I make sure the value is queries and passes into the IF clause if it's either undefined or has a value, which is not dialog?

Thanks for help!

Comment: id `data.options.role` is `undefined`, then your first if statement should be hit. What are `A` and `B` looking for?

Comment: data.options.fromHashChange == true and self.options._transDelta == 1 - both are ok and working correclty. Only after adding the third check for dialog, I'm not getting into the IF if "undefined"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting an undefined object property in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property-in-javascript) and [How to check for undefined in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985771/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript).

Comment: Are you sure `A` and `B` are true? You can see from the following fiddle that your original condition is hit when `.role` is undefined: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/NSDgL/1

Comment: hm. seems to be another error... need more than 1sec. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - you were correct :-) My transdelta variable was ..."tainted"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant `undefined` type of javascript, for that you need to use `typeof` like this:

```
if(  A && B && typeof data.options.role != "undefined" &&
      data.options.role != "dialog" )
```

You also need to make sure that `A` and `B` are coming truthy too.